# Windows Form c# Reading and Writing to the same File on the same form Error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am currently trying to complete this c# windows form application. I am running into trouble.

Here is an image of my form...

[image]

The point of this form is too allow a user to input the data above. On the back end it should find the lowest test score, remove it from an array, and then when the user clicks "save student", the 3 lines of data ( The "Student Name", avg of 5 Test, and Letter grade based on the average ), should be saved to the students.txt file.

***HOWEVER, my issue is can be seen in the list box below. My issue is that I am loading the data from the "students.txt" file ( using pre filled dummy data ), and I am getting an error each time I try to save the student ( because I cant read and write to the same file ) and the program will stop running.***

Clicking on any of the pre filled data brings up another form with the data loaded into labels and that works just fine...
[image]

How can I stop this error so I can proceed with my work? I also am having trouble understanding the instructions where the data should be in a 2d array.

Here is an image of the instructions before I move on with my code. I am sure I can diverge from the instructions a bit.

[image]

Here is the code for my main Form...

```
namespace Tes3Part2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<PersonEntry> contactList = new List<PersonEntry>();
        private List<string> contactListNames = new List<string>();

        private InfromationForm personInfo = new InfromationForm();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("students.txt");

                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    PersonEntry person = new PersonEntry();

                    person.Name = inputFile.ReadLine();
                    person.AverageScore = inputFile.ReadLine();
                    person.LetterGrade = inputFile.ReadLine();

                    contactList.Add(person);
                    contactListNames.Add(person.Name);
                }

                contactListNames.Sort();

                int x = 0;

                while (x < contactListNames.Count)
                {
                    contactList.Insert(x, contactList[SequentialSearch(contactList, contactListNames[x])]);
                    studentsListBox.Items.Add(contactList[x].Name);
                    x++;
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome.");
            }


        }
        private int SequentialSearch(List<PersonEntry> inputList, string value)
        {
            bool found = false;
            int index = 0;
            int position = -1;

            while (!found && index < inputList.Count)
            {
                if (inputList[index].Name == value)
                {
                    found = true;
                    position = index;
                }

                index++;
            }

            return position;
        }

        private void StudentsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            personInfo.nameLabel.Text = contactList[studentsListBox.SelectedIndex].Name;
            personInfo.scoreLabel.Text = contactList[studentsListBox.SelectedIndex].AverageScore;
            personInfo.letterLabel.Text = contactList[studentsListBox.SelectedIndex].LetterGrade;
            personInfo.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            double test1 = (double.Parse(t1TestBox.Text));
            double test2 = (double.Parse(t1TestBox.Text));
            double test3 = (double.Parse(t1TestBox.Text));
            double test4 = (double.Parse(t1TestBox.Text));
            double test5 = (double.Parse(t1TestBox.Text));
            double average = (test1 * test2 * test3 * test4 * test5) / 5;

            // Declare a StreamWriter variable. 
            StreamWriter outputFile;
            // Create a file and get a StreamWriter object.
            outputFile = File.CreateText("students.txt");
            // Write the info to the file. 
            outputFile.WriteLine(nameTextBox.Text);
            outputFile.WriteLine(average);
            outputFile.WriteLine("F");
            outputFile.Close();

            // Let the user know the name was written. 
            MessageBox.Show("The employee's name was added to the file EmployeePayroll.txt, located" +
                "in the Debug File");

        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for my Person Class

```
class PersonEntry
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _average;
        private string _letterGrade;

        public PersonEntry()
        {
            _name = "";
            _average = "";
            _letterGrade = "";
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public string AverageScore
        {
            get { return _average; }
            set { _average = value; }
        }

        public string LetterGrade
        {
            get { return _letterGrade; }
            set { _letterGrade = value; }
        }

    }
```

Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Comment: You don't close the file after reading from it. Missing _inputFile.Close()_ but it is better to use the _using_ statement IE _using(StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader(....))_

Comment: whre is inputFile.Close() suppose to go?

Comment: After you have finished to read. But, again, look at how to use the _using_ statement. This is a lot better when you need to be sure that resources like file handles are fred as soon as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Steve mentioned you make use of the using statement while reading and writing to the file.

```
using (StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("students.txt"))
        {

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                PersonEntry person = new PersonEntry();

                person.Name = inputFile.ReadLine();
                person.AverageScore = inputFile.ReadLine();
                person.LetterGrade = inputFile.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter outputFile = File.CreateText("students.txt"))
        {
            // Write the info to the file. 
            outputFile.WriteLine(nameTextBox.Text);
            outputFile.WriteLine(average);
            outputFile.WriteLine("F");
            outputFile.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks that did work, but then it just overloaded the file. I stopped it by appending instead of writting.